# Animate ONLY some items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am trying to animate only some items in my recyclerview based on some condition in the data set. The overrides look like :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlayerViewHolder playerViewHolder, final int position) {
    // Some basic logic
    setOnlineStatus(playerViewHolder, position);
}

private void setOnlineStatus(PlayerViewHolder playerViewHolder, int position) {
    User player = players.get(position);
    if(player.getIsOnline()){
        playerViewHolder.playerImageView.startAnimation(pulseAnimation);
    } else {
        playerViewHolder.playerImageView.clearAnimation();
    }
}

public static class PlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView counterTextView;
    CircularImageView playerImageView;

    PlayerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        counterTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
        playerImageView = (CircularImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerImageView);
    }
}
```

This animates the player items which are online. And if they go offline, I cancel the animation.

The problem starts when I try to scroll in the recyclerview. I understand the viewholders are being reused, but this causes my valid players which are online to stop animating, I guess they get recycled with the offline player data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you aware of RecyclerView.ItemAnimator class?

Comment: Yes, but how will it fit in my scenario. All i want is to animate only some items on initial load, or when a notifyItemChanged() is called. Can you point me to right direction here.

Comment: i think you should write your own `ItemAnimator` and use it by calling directly `ItemAnimator#animateChange` or `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged`

Comment: I see, but can you explain whats wrong with the above approach. I have the textview as well inside my adapter, but the values of that doesnt change, when i scroll up or down. This is only affecting the animations any reason why so ?

Comment: well you adding the animation to a physical View that as you know can be reused, i believe that RecyclerView somehow "reattaches" the pending Animators to the target reused Views when view is scrolled

Comment: Thanks, looking at the ItemAnimator class, I still dont understand how will it fix the problem. As these are all infinite animations on the images, what am I suppose to do when the recyclerview is scrolled. And also where do i put the check for online vs offline. Sorry but this seems more complicated then i thought it was.

Comment: you should see: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.java take a look into `runPendingAnimations()` you can extend this class to add your own animations